# Why do Java errors prevent me from building in my C++ perspective?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I recently installed CDT for Eclipse and made a simple hello world C++ project.

When I try to build the C++ project, an error surfaces:

```
Syntax Error: 'for each' statements are only available if source level
    is 1.5 or greater
```

This error pertains to code in java. Why is the error stopping me from building a C++ project? I have tried Window > Open Perspective > C/C++, but I still can't build my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the C/C++ perspective, click the Make tab (the icon is a green bull's-eye target). Then you can double-click the C++ target representing the product you want. Or click Add target if necessary, and configure things… have fun.

I've personally abandoned CDT for building, although the editor is alright.